# Automatically remove '[solved]' from questions

Tags: discussion, title, community-user

At least a few hundred questions have `[SOLVED]`, `[Solved]` or `[solved]` in their titles. I have removed some, but there are just too many.

Can this be automated by the "community user" or so?

Comment: Why are you removing them? What's the value?

Comment: Yes, of course. Really tired of this [solved].

Comment: We could recycle our review drones for this: offer 2 rep per edit and I'm pretty sure all instances of `[solved]` would disappear overnight.

Comment: @Oded - education. This is not a forum, and if the problem is 'solved', then one may better post an answer for it (sometimes there is no such); in addition, it is redundant - we already have a way to mark a question as answered, accepted, etc.

Comment: We prevent the inclusion of "problem" in question titles. Why wouldn't we prevent [solved], {solved}, (solved), etc.?

Comment: @unit, filtering `problem` led to question titles containing `pr0blem`, `porblem`, and other assorted flavors. Filtering `solved` will probably lead to `s0lved` or `sloved` questions.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: No doubt. Which is part of the reason filtering "problem" from titles is a bad idea. But, if we're going to live with bad ideas, this idea isn't as bad as some others. (I was being a bit "tongue-in-cheek".)

Comment: Related: [Community Edit Request - “Solved” / “fixed” / “Answered”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172501/community-edit-request-solved-fixed-answered)

Comment: If you are removing them, are you also ensure that an answer is actually posted?

Comment: @Andy, if there is an answer, I post it as a community wiki post, and give a disclaimer.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86278/detect-edits-to-add-solved-or-resolved-to-the-title-and-direct-the-user-to-a

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Removing [solved] from titles automatically doesn't, well, "solve" anything. Sure, that gets rid of a pet peeve of many of us, but it's usually an indication that something else needs to happen as well.

- The OP might simple be able to accept one of the answers that [solved] his question.
- The OP included the answer into his question, while he should simply make that an actual answer and accept it.
- And the question perhaps could use some editing in general.

All those situations are left unaddressed by simply removing [solved] or one of its varieties.

So do it by hand. And if you do it at all (and that might be a big **if**), see what the global state of the post is and address all issues.

Comment: Another possibility I've seen recently: the OP removes the code from the question.  (on fix-this-code questions, possibly combined with including the answer by editing the fix into the question's code)

Comment: and of course, such edits should be rolled back, or the question removed.  There's no point in keeping "what's wrong with this code" questions where the code has been fixed.