# Suggest to post answer / accept one when changing title to "Solved"

Tags: feature-request, title

I see that many questions contain the title "Solved" in it ([see the results yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Asolved)).

The typical story is that somebody is happy because he found the solution to his issue, so he updates the title and, maybe:

- accepts an answer
- writes the solution in a comment
- writes the solution in the same question
- just leaves

I just edited [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28124291/1983854), moving the solution to an answer as Community Wiki. However, this could be solved in a better way.

What if we did something like the following upon seeing that somebody is adding 'Solved' in the title of his own question?

- Show a little comment saying "hey, your problem seems to be solved, check this link and see what is best to do in this case". And show him how to accept an answer or post his own one.

I see that some time ago somebody suggested to [Automatically remove '[solved]' from questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262123/automatically-remove-solved-from-questions) . I think going to the core of the problem can improve the quality of the site in these cases.

Note that the suggested duplicate [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) addresses to "what to do if we encounter this situation", whereas here I am suggesting another "what to do to prevent it from happening".

Comment: OK, but the "damage" to the question also needs to be fixed. These can be of various types. I usually rollback, and comment to vote and/or accept, and self-answer with accept if necessary. For typos, of course, no action required except to ensure closed (with no answers, preferreably)

Comment: @BillWoodger I totally agree. This makes me think about adding the question in a queue review so that these improvements can also be manually checked.

Comment: I'm glad you did this, as it was one I had noted. I was following the advice in [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que). When it suggests giving the OP a chance to do the right thing first; also flag some Qs that are closable that should not be answered, and finally make a CW, as you did. I slowed down to a more glacial pace when the unfriendly comments about necroposting started to become a deterrent. I suspect on 68.8k you are likely to get less complaints about necroposting than I do on 1.7k...

Comment: @BrianTompsett: Necro'ing is fine, just don't do lots of posts in a short period of time or it floods the front page.

Comment: Don't change title to solved. [Love if we could get it removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172501/community-edit-request-solved-fixed-answered).

Comment: Although it doesn't help the backlog, how about just making "Solved" a banned word in titles?

Comment: Half the question you list [have no accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Asolved+hasaccepted%3Ano) @TheBlueDog that would mean it'd force whoever edited it to remove that word....might still help the back log *a little*.

Comment: @Pureferret: That's very true, it's a win/win situation. ;)

Comment: @BrianTompsett The difference is mostly that at 1.7k each of your suggested edits has to be reviewed by at least 3 people. Doing lots of edits like this is so much more time efficient when it is done by >2k users.

Comment: @TheBlueDog yes, that is an idea. But since this would just "kill" the attempt but not go to the root, my suggestion is to make it "blacklisted + trigger a recommendation".

Comment: Just discussed this over on MetaAU- http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14045/178596 - as AU is smaller it was easy to deal with manually. Also, if you filter the search to take out closed and answered questions, it reduces the workload a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Asolved+closed%3Ano+hasaccepted%3Ano

Comment: I am updating these questions using this comment _I posted your "fixed" comment into an answer. You can mark it as accepted to show the problem is solved. Note in [so] changing the title to "solved" is not what we do; instead, we either post an answer of select the one that solved our issue._. or _remove "solved" from title -> if it is solved, mark the correct answer of post yours_.